# How do I implement a jQuery UI dialog modal in a WP plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery-ui

I have a WordPress plugin I created that creates custom top level menu and submenu fine. The submenu calls this, (see code beneath) the BranchMaintenance PHP form, which shows branches in a table, ex the dbase, (using `$wpdb`).

It's getting the jQuery UI dialog modal form to popup which is the problem. Doubtless my code is responsible, 
...clueless re things like no name variable outer/toplevel functions as per in the code
     e.g. `$(function() {`

I am trying to action the scripts I need to 
    a) hide the dialog form initially  (it appears above my table of branch data)..probably got this way wrong
    b) display it when called (this still as per the original demo code)

```
<div class="wrap" id="main">
<form name="Sandwich Baron Branch Maintenance" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%   7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">  



//This was placed in the head of a normal HTML form in the Demo 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-        form.html'...field validation is removed for now.
<script>
$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    //$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );


    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


                if ( bValid ) {
                    //Appnds the data captured to the table in the main page
                    //$( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                    //  "<td>" + txtBrname.val() + "</td>" + 
                    //  "<td>" + txtStrAddress.val() + "</td>" + 
                    //  "<td>" + txtManager.val() + "</td>" +
                    //"</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#create-branch" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });


});


</script>


<?php
function fn_DeleteBranch(Id)
{
   //$wpdb->   etc etc ; //deletes this branch (by Id) from the dbase
}
?>


<style>    
 body { font-size: 62.5%; }     
 label, input { display:block; }    
 input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }     
 fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }     
 h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }     
 div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }     
 div#users-contain table 
{ margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }    
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th 
{ border: 1px solid #eee;  padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }     
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }     
.validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; } 

</style>

<?php
// Hook for adding Dialog form HOPEFULLY
add_action('admin_init', "#dialog-form" );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_Deregister_scripts' ); 
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts-options_page-{page}', 'myplugin_admin_scripts' ); 

function my_Deregister_scripts()  {        
   wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui' );  //Deregister WP's version    
}  

function myplugin_admin_scripts(){
   //  syntax   wp_enqueue_script( $handle,$src,$deps,$ver,$in_footer );
   //  $src  = the url where the scripts are stored
   //  $in_footer Normally scripts are placed in the <head> section, so defaults to false

   //wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-bgiframe-2.1.2' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-button' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-position' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-resizable' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core' );  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget' );

//jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-   style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}
?>


<div id="dialog-form" title="Branch Editing">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="BrName">Branch Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtBrname" id="txtBrName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="Tel">Tel</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTel" id="txtTel" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />



</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<?php             
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"; 
    echo "<tr> 
    <th>ID</th> 
    <th>Branch Name</th> 
    <th>Express?</th> 
    <th>Str.Address</th> 
    <th>Area</th>
    <th>Manager</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Tel</th>
    <th>Cell</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </tr>"; 

global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_sbbranches");

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table      
foreach ($myrows as $row) {               
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrId. '</td>'; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrName. '</td>'; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrTel. '</td>';

    echo '<td style="border:none;"><button onclick="create-branch(' . $row->Id. ')"></td>';
            echo '<td style="border:none;"><button onclick="fn_DeleteBranch(' . $row->Id. ')"></td>'; 

            echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    // close table> 
    echo "</table>";
?> 
<button id="create-branch(' 0 ')" >Create new branch</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm not clear on what *exactly* you need, maybe I could offer a few pointers.

First off, the documentation on the various sites have everything you need, so you should visit the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org), and [jQuery UI examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

**Hooks**

admin_init : You can deregister/register scripts here. If you intend on using a custom jquery ui script for example :

```
 function my_register_scripts()
 {
      wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui' ); //Deregister WP's version
      wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) ); //Register your own
 }
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_register_scripts' );
```

admin_menu: add your plugin page, hook specific page for your scripts also

```
 function my_menu()
 {
      $admin_page = add_menu_page(/*Look at the codex for the args, link below*/); //Add your page

      //use the $admin_page variable for targeted script loading

      add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $admin_page, 'function_that_enqueues_css_here' );
      add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $admin_page, 'function_that_enqueues_js_here' );

 }
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_menu' );
```

[add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

**EDIT: Dialog Example**

Heres a simple modal dialog example that opens a form :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#form-wrap').dialog({
           autoOpen: true, //FALSE if you open the dialog with, for example, a button click
           title: 'My Form',
           modal: true
      });
 });
```

The code above assumes you have  or other tag with the id of 'form-wrap'. Inside you place your form.

**Folder Structure**

I could be wrong, but I don't think this matters much, I just put my .js files in a /js folder, css in a /css folder, etc...

Use [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) when enqueueing files from your plugin directory.

The [jQuery UI Dialog's page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) should have all the examples you need.

When I use those dialogs, I generally generate html on the page (display:none), and use that for the dialog popup.

Hope some of this helped.

**EDIT**

Also, I think customizing your own jQuery UI script on the jQuery UI website will give you less files to enqueue.

**EDIT 2**

You have errors in your add_actions if the code above is what you're using.

```
 add_action('admin_init', "#dialog-form" );
```

The second argument should be a PHP function, that looks like the ID of your HTML div.

```
 add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts-options_page-{page}', 'myplugin_admin_scripts' );
```

I'm pretty sure {page} is supposed to be replaced by the specific page you want to call the scripts on.

If jQuery is your main issue, I suggest maybe getting it working on a simple html page disassociated from your site until you have it working, then get the hooks right.

Comment: Thanks, I have done pretty much that now..took a while to put the bits together. I do have my Admin TopLevel plugin working with it's submenus, one of which drives the mentioned BranchMaint form,..which is to have the popup / dialog which should handle the Edits and/or Insert NewBranch, and use $wpdb to insert or uppdate accordingly. However The popup functionality is still not working. I have updated my code above, with action hooks to my-functions, if that is of any help.

Comment: I am looking into your (Shane) suggestion, researching tags etc. 2 weeks of php and wpress. (11 years of c# Asp.net). also researching auto updating the parent form.

Comment: See my second Edit - Also, be sure to check the source on the rendered page to see if the scripts are called, and anything plugin like Firebug for Firefox can help with javascript errors.

Comment: Does your plugin file look exactly like the code above? It could be helpful if you could show me your plugin file.

Comment: Yep, my mistake,...it should be a call to a pho function.

Comment: and {page} also yep. Replaced it with  add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_admin_scripts' ); 
Then Got it working fine on std html page (just a copy of their demo with my own folders and et voila no problem) JQuery it is... checked my 2011 & 2012 themes and edited Header.php file added the Enque to jquery in it before the wp_head function. It's a fresh install of WP 3.3.1 on my WAMPserver WinPC.  BUT on my page the jquery initiates are being passed by,..i.e. not invoked. SO my 'form' with the fields in it which is supposed to popup is visible with the rest of the table and fields immediately.

Comment: and the popup button 'AddBranch' does zilch....Thinking I must go with your suggestion / modal popup form for now (time running out) and keep playing/researching this JQuery thing later

Comment: If I were to use my 'fieldset in its form tags and your example dialog .. I imagine i would be well on my way?

Comment: One question re your popup,  how do you call it from a button click? I see no event associated with it for a button, or a function Id , which the button's on-click can reference.

Comment: I just redid the form with no JQueryUI stuff in it, just the table and fieldset and your popup dialog code (referenced the #form-wrap div on my button click, but the div + fieldset still display on the page and don't popup.

Comment: i put an alert in the document.ready function, but that does'nt show either.  I imagine my WP plugin is not responding to JQuery...Back to the RnD drawing board. Thx though for your help ,appreciated.

Comment: To open a dialog on button click, you set up the dialog with "autoOpen: false" parameter, then on button click, you do $('#the_dialog_you_setup').dialog( 'open' );

Comment: The dialog can be opened with any click event. A simple achnor on the page could do the trick:

<a href="#" id="open-form">Open form</a>

and in your javascript:

$('#open-form').click(function(){
     $('#the_form_you_setup').dialog( 'open' );
});

Answer (score 4):

You should do these:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts',     'admin_scripts' ); 
function admin_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );
}
```

then you should use:

```
jQuery('<div> Hii! <div>').dialog({ modal:true, width:600 });
```